# getting bash newgrp functionality on startup

Tags: bash

As a part of my setups, I often need, in our environements, to use

```
newgrp voodoo
```

If I try to put it in the `.bashrc` file, I get infinite loops.

Any ideas how to get the same functionality automatically loaded in startup?

Answer (score 11):

There are 2 scripts that will get started once you start bash:

- `.bashrc` for interactive shells
- `.bash_profile` for login shells

Depending on the way you run the `newgrp` command one of them will be executed:

- `newgrp - your_group` will start a new login shell and thus read `.bash_profile`
- `newgrp your_group` (**without** the dash) will start a new interactive shell reading `.bashrc`

If you don't source one file from the other you should be able to circumvent the recursion by choosing the right combination of startup script and newgrp switch

- `newgrp - ...` in `.bashrc` will work
- `newgrp ...` in `.bash_profile` will work

The other two combinations will lead to the recursion you already described.
If one of both files sources the other as it is often seen you'll be in trouble anyways.

BTW.: if `.bash_profile` doesn't exist bash will read the file `.profile` instead. I just mention it as some experts even manage to source their `.bashrc` from there.

If neither combination applies to your setup you might have to take resort to shell scripting instead. The environment variable `$GROUPS` should report the group you are member of, so something like:

```
[ "$GROUPS" = "200" ] || newgrp your_group
```

or whatever the id of your voodoo group is might help.

Comment: Looks like input it to the ~/.bash_profile gets the job done. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the current group id with the command `id -gn`, then call `newgrp` only if you aren't in the right group. So your `.bashrc` could include

```
# Switch groups, but only if necessary
if [[ `id -gn` != "mygroup" ]]
then
    newgrp mygroup
    exit
fi
```

Side note, this syntax also works for ksh.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu: This solution may need adjustment on different distros.

The out-of-the-box Ubuntu setup for a new user is to have `.profile` and `.bashrc` startup files; in particular note that `.bash_profile` doesn't exist by default. If that's the case on your system too you should be able to append this to `.profile` to switch automatically to the desired group on [shell] startup; note that this should be the last line in `.profile`,

```
exec newgrp voodoo
```

Background info: The `.profile` calls `.bashrc`. I found that if I call `newgrp` from the `.profile` it avoids looping; since it does create a new shell I prefix it with `exec` to replace the existing shell with the new shell (so no need to `exit` twice when you finish your bash session) - but also because of the `exec` it has to be the last line in `.profile`.

It may also be helpful to review articles etc. describing the various bash startup files; I found the zwischenzugs [blog article](https://zwischenzugs.com/2019/02/27/bash-startup-explained/) gives a good overview, where it also becomes clear why the above line should go in `.profile` (only need to run `newgrp` once) rather than in `.bashrc` (would run `newgrp` when starting child shell - unnecessary since the effective group was set the first time in `.profile`; also since `newgrp` itself starts a non-login, interactive shell, it will run `.bashrc` once more - leading to the infinite loop issue described in the question)